# Automatically purge dropped tables in Oracle

Tags: oracle, hibernate, oracle-18c

I am using an Oracle 18c database in a build system.

One of my builds is for a JPA/Hibernate project, which is configured as "create-drop". This means it will create all tables during startup and drop all of them again at the end.

The problem is: I can't configure Hibernate to create "drop ... purge" statements.

It seems that as a result the recycle bin has grown with each build, exceeding now the maximum allowed database size of 12 GB - and I am not even able to open the database anymore:

```
alter database open
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-12954: The request exceeds the maximum allowed database size of 12 GB.
```

I have now droped the PDB and created a new one - but this will last for at most a month, before I run into the same problem again.

My question: Is there any option to tell Oracle to *immediately* purge dropped tables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any option to tell Oracle to immediately purge dropped tables?

That would be [disabling the recycle bin](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/admin/managing-tables.html#GUID-371BE1F5-5B21-4B88-B85E-BB9A773C9FA6), if only for the current session. Include `ALTER SESSION SET recyclebin = OFF` in your build process, or, if this is a development system, you can consider turning it off via the instance initialization parameter.

Alternatively, you can choose running the build as a dedicated Oracle user; you will then `DROP USER ... CASCADE` at the end, which will drop all user's tables and other objects without placing them in the recycle bin.

Comment: There is also the option of running a `purge recyclebin` to purge the current user's recycle bin or `purge dba_recyclebin` to purge all users' recycle bins.

Comment: Thanks, I will go with the initialization parameter. Dropping the USER at the end would mean much more overhead in the build.

Comment: @JustinCave I tried `purge recyclebin` - but as it didn't finished after half an hour I would guess that this is nothing for a cronjob. And it is much more overhead to include it in the build, too.